# How to know if the request is ajax in asp.net in Application_Error()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, application-error

How to know if the request is ajax in asp.net  in  Application_Error()

I want to handle app error in Application_Error().If the request is ajax  and  some exception is thrown,then write the error in  log file and return a json data that contains error tips for client .
Else if the request is synchronism and some exception is thrown ,write the error in log file and then redirect to a error page.

but now i cant judge which kind  the request is . I want to get "X-Requested-With" from header ,unfortunately    keys of  headers don't contain "X-Requested-With" key ,why?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Testing for the request header should work. For example:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult AjaxTest()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

and in `Application_Error`:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    bool isAjaxCall = string.Equals("XMLHttpRequest", Context.Request.Headers["x-requested-with"], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    Context.ClearError();
    if (isAjaxCall)
    {
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        Context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        Context.Response.Write(
            new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
                new { error = "some nasty error occured" }
            )
        );
    }

}
```

and then send some Ajax request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get('@Url.Action("AjaxTest", "Home")', function (result) {
        if (result.error) {
            alert(result.error);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that Context.Request.Headers["x-requested-with"] would return "XMLHttpRequest". I send a ajax request above code return null.

Comment: @dayulu, absolutely, the code I have shown you was tested. There could be another issue with your code: if you have some custom global filter which intercepts exceptions and performs a redirect to an error page then the x-requested-with header will be lost.

Comment: You are right! I get null ,because the request redirect one time! Thank you very much!

Comment: This doesn't work in global.asax. Use `__CALLBACKID` instead. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

You can also wrap the Context.Request (of the type HttpRequest) in a HttpRequestWrapper which contains a method IsAjaxRequest.

```
bool isAjaxCall = new HttpRequestWrapper(Context.Request).IsAjaxRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to add custom headers in the client side ajax call. Refer http://forums.asp.net/t/1229399.aspx/1

Try looking for this header value in the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this.

```
    private static bool IsAjaxRequest()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";
    }
```