# Ajax based web application - Mocking a real request after facebook login

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm building an ajax based web application which lets Facebook users who login to the application, enjoy certain advanced options of the application, like saving their settings, etc` (the user doesn't HAVE to login to his facebook account, but it gives him extra privileges).

I'm using the C# Facebook SDK on ASP.NET WebForms platform.
The entire application is AJAX based, which means that after the user decides to log in (using Facebook JS API) and reload the page, the entire communication from that point on is ajax based.

I was wondering if there's a way to make those AJAX requests in the same way I would've done it manually through the browser - meaning that **all related facebook and current session cookies will be sent in it's headers**. I'm asking this since I don't want to create a custom protocol which will identify the user of the ajax request.

Hope what i'm after is clear through this post...

Comment: When I create local AJAX (by local I mean requests to the same domain) calls using JQuery or JavaScript, does my browser send cookies information like it normally would if I say - click on a hyper link which leads to a page in the same website? I'm asking this since I only want to reply those ajax calls for a person whose already logged in, and I'll have no indication for that unless the ajax request includes the related cookies... hope that's a bit clearer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my app screen shot, it is ajax as in your case and:

- this ajax call is to local ajax(=to same domain)
- it sends cookies for each ajax call and anchor link(done by browser, send stored cookie in browser for each call )
- **X-Requested-With** field in the request header helps you understand if this is ajax call or not, more information here: [How to know if the request is ajax in asp.net in Application_Error()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551424/how-to-know-if-the-request-is-ajax-in-asp-net-in-application-error)

[image]

Comment: Sometimes the solution is so trivial that you don't think of it :)